# Good way to implment a .NET Service layer pattern with REST calls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to come up with a good way to have a service layer that is mainly making REST API calls to an external API. I've currently got a .NET Core 2.0 project where my services are being injected into my controllers, and I'm making calls that way. However, in my services themselves, I'm making calls to external APIs that require an access token. My current architecture has mostly been thrown together pretty quickly just to kind of "get things working", but now I was to decouple things a bit more and make it more testable. Here is an example of one of my service methods to illustrate where I'm at, an implementation of ISomeSearchService:

```
 public async Task<SearchDataResponse> SearchAsync(string query, string accessToken)
    {
        SearchDataResponsedataResponse = null;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("www.somesite.com/api");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

            IList<KeyValuePair<string, object>> parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>()
            {
                KeyValuePair.Create<string, object>( "searchTerm", query ),
            };

            var response = await client.GetAsync("/search" + UriFormatter.AsQueryString(parameters));

            if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                dataResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchDataResponse>(responseBody);
            }

        }

        return dataResponse;
    }
```

I know this is riddled with issues. Namely one of the biggest to me is that is constructing this HTTP client in the service itself. I would like to abstract that out, and maybe pass in a client to the service that is already constructed some way. That way in my tests, I can pass in mock clients to be able to test these methods without having to make actual HTTP calls. I'm not sure if there is a better way to handle that though. I can't find much guidance on service layers that are making HTTP calls. Most documentation I find is related to calling a DB directly.

Another issue is that I don't like passing the access token directly into the service. Since I was limited on time, I just did that to get things working, but I'm not happy with it.

Does anyone have some experience with this or a design that I could look into that would decouple this out more?

Comment: Inject the http client and credentials into your service.

Comment: I thought about that, but my services are configured to be injected automatically via the services container in startup. The http client would change depending on how it's being called (ie. different uri). Another issue is that it requires the consumer (the controller) to construct an httpclient in every call, which I would like to avoid. I would like my controller just to call something like "service.SearchAsync(query)" and not be concerned about the underlying logic of how that search is being performed (whether it's an http call or reading right from a database).

Comment: You can make a factory method to help configure the client. And you don't need an instance per call -- configure the DI container for a singleton HttpClient. And you can certainly change the URI per use.

Comment: Here's an article on why use singleton `HttpClient` as @Jasen suggested https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to inject an HttpClient instance. You can extract an interface from HttpClient to assist with mocking.

```
public interface IHttpClient : IDisposable
{
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request);
}
```

You will need an implementation that constructs instances of `HttpClient` but you can also use the interface to mock the request.

Now your service codes against the `IHttpClient`

```
public class SearchService : ISomeSearchService
{
    private readonly IHttpClient httpClient;

    public SearchService(IHttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }
}
```

Alter your request so that you send an `HttpRequestMessage` instead of using `.GetAsync()` that way you can alter the Authorization header per request.

```
public async Task<SearchDataResponse> SearchAsync(string query, string accessToken)
{
    using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri)
    {
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        ...
    }
}
```

Then register the singleton HttpClient

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpClient, HttpClientFactory>();
services.AddScoped<ISomeSearchService, SearchService>();
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Your solution along the lines of what I had in mind. Also like the idea of having the HttpClient singleton. What do you think about this solution: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/160236? I think it may suite me well because I have other services that use different base URLs.

Comment: That seems sensible. You just don't want to create tons of HttpClients.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to come up with a way to avoid that. I could use a singleton HttpClient, but I would have to have a way to modify the base address in a thread-safe way. Or I could have multiple HttpClients that handle different base addresses, like the solution I posted had mentioned. I just want to avoid potentially having to change the base address on every service method call.

Comment: Also, what do you think about passing the access token in like that? To me it seems a little weird to be passing it in directly, but I'm not really sure what the best practices around that are.

Comment: I don't see a problem. If they don't change then pass them into the constructor.

Comment: FYI, HttpRequest is an abstract class